# Dashboard display goes dark

Tags: lights, dashboard

I have a 62 plate vw passat 2.0 tdi bluemotion sport estate. When i put the ignition key in i get the usual lights lighting up on the dash and the info system however when i start the engine the display goes out. Nothing at all. Fuel guage registers empty and speedo is at zero. Lights, indicators, parking sensors all work as does the radio. Although the indicators work you cant hear them?
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant, but my Skoda (from the VW stable) has a "feature" that if the system detects a low level of ambient light, it turns off the instrument lighting, until I turn on the headlights. The ambient light sensor is on the instrument panel and can't be seen unless looked at very carefully. Personally I think the feature is total crap. I thought there was a fault until I read about it.

Comment: What does "62 plate" mean?

Comment: @David in UK a 62 plate is 2062 which is 2012 + 50 to indicate the second half of the year **2012**. It is in the form AA62 ZZZ where AA is the local authority area and ZZZ is a sequential series of letters.

Comment: @David we have had many numbering systems and each time they ran out of combinations they had to devise another system. This one should last half a century.